# -webkit-text-stroke CSS property gives uneven color opacity with overlapping region in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I tried to put a stroke with some opacity/alpha in its color by "-webkit-text-stroke".

I got uneven opacity in color for overlapping and non-overlapping area of stroke.

Below is **sample code** line.

```
<div style="font-size:300px;-webkit-text-stroke:60px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);">Ho</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

In output, overlapping area is more darker than non-overlapping area.
I don't understand why is it so and what should be done to get uniform opacity in stroke text.

Moreover this issue is only with Chrome, for Mozilla Firefox and Safari it works fine. 
We can draw this in Canvas or provide spacing between characters to avoid overlapping. But it would be nice to have a solution in CSS/HTML.

Comment: This looks to me as though Chrome is doing it *right*. Alpha values should be additive.

Comment: Also, this is an experimental property and shouldn't be used in production - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke

Comment: @Paulie_D  This might be right as per Chrome additive response for Alpha values, but I wish to have uniform alpha for stroke. Firefox and Safari doesn't add alpha value and gives uniform composition of Alpha.
Is there a way to get the same in Chrome.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will not use it in production, for that i have used HTML5 Canvas. I just want to know if it is possible by CSS/HTML.

Comment: You say "In Firefox it works fine", but it doesn't here; the stroke is cut off to the right. I had to append a `&nbsp;` to the right to fix that. Anyway, a workaround for Chrome would be to set `letter-spacing:30px`.

Comment: @MrLister Yes stroke is cut off but my concern is about uniform opacity in stroke which is delivered by FireFox.
Spacing might be a solution but i can't add extra space in my text. So i have to make opacity uniform somehow.

Comment: You can try to add letter-spacing property in order to add some spacing among letters so the stroke doesn't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradient with alpha values as a text stroke, and then the alpha will not add up:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(10, 14, 15, 0.3), rgba(10, 14, 15, 0.3));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1vw transparent;
```